# How to describe the semantics of a language?

Tags: semantics, execution, formal-semantics

For syntax there is the [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) ISO 14977 standard.

for runtime we have [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) ISO 23271 standard

see also [Simple definition of "semantics" as it is commonly used in relation to programming languages/APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277798)

but how to describe the transition from EBNF to CLI specs in declarative way?
i.e. is it enough to use the [S-attributed grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-attributed_grammar)? Which standard define the syntax of such grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to define the semantics of a language.  All of them have to express somehow the relationship between the program text and "what it computes".

A short but incomplete list of basic techniques:

- Define an interpreter ("operational semantics")
- Define a map from the source code to an enriched lambda calculus ("denotational semantics")
- Define a map from the source code to another well-defined language ("transformational semantics")

Essentially, these are computations defined over the source text of a program instance.

You can *implement* these computations in many different ways.  *One* way to implement them might be "S-attributed" grammars, although why you would want to restrict yourself to only S-attributes rather than a standard attributed grammar with inherited attributes is beyond me.

Given that there are so many ways to do this, I doubt you are going to find a *standard*.    Certainly the programming langauge committees aren't using one.  Heck, they won't even use a standard for BNF.

Comment: I want some examples of denotational semantics in application to CLI/CLR (instead of pure lambda calculus). Is it possible to enrich it to the level of modern programming runtime?

Comment: I think you missed the point.  Denotational semantics (DS) *is* transformational semantics with the target language *being* the lambda calculus (with some additonal convenience operations like math on numbers, arrays and structs).   So a DS for CLI/CLR would produce the lambda calculus equivalent.    Can you actually build such a mapping for a something as complex as CLI/CLR/C#?   I think the claim is you can, but it is a LOT of sweat, and if you had, what would you do with it?  ...

Comment: ...It is a kind of chicken-and-egg problem; without machinery to process it, there's little point in producing such a semantics, and without the semantics, there is little motivation to building the machinery that can process it.  So the project is sort of twice as big as doing just the semantic part, and that part is already as big as building a compiler (because that's what you are doing in essence).  I've been interested for years, and have made actually big engineering investments in source-language processing technology (see my bio), but haven't had the energy to go down this path yet.